# pass array of array to the controller not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass array value from view to the controller action using ajax. I have created jquery and controller method as bellow, but its not working.

in my javascript file,

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    var data = [];
    $("#utiltyTable tr.maintr").each(function () {

        var selectedMail = [];
        var selectedMobile = [];

        var categoryId = $(this).find("td.uCategory").find("input[type='hidden']").val();

        $(this).find("td.uEmail").find("select :selected").map(function (i, el) {
            selectedMail.push({ "value": $(el).val(), "item": $(el).text() });
        });

        $(this).find("td.uSMS").find("select :selected").map(function (i, el) {
            selectedMobile.push({ "value": $(el).val(), "item": $(el).text() });
        });

        data.push({ categoryId: categoryId, selectedMail: JSON.stringify(selectedMail), selectedMobile: JSON.stringify(selectedMobile) })


    });

    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UtilityEmailSMS", "Account")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });

});
```

Controller action method as bellow,

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UtilityEmailSMS(string[] data)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

I am getting string[] array.but all key value as null
[image]

Comment: But you try to pass array of objects, not array of string.

Comment: if i use `public ActionResult UtilityEmailSMS(object[] data)` i am also getting null in `data`

Comment: Its just `selectedMail: selectedMail` (not `JSON.stringify(selectedMail)`) and ditto for`selectedMobile: selectedMobile`. You need a model to bind to that matches the data you sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should accept array of objects instead of string, as you are passing object array from ajax.

So create a model for same.

```
public class Mail
  {
    public string value {get;set;}
    public string item {get;set;}
  }

public class Test
{
    public string categoryId {get;set;}
    public Mail[] selectedMail {get;set;}
    public Mail[] selectedMobile {get; set;}
}
```

Then

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UtilityEmailSMS(Test[] data)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: OP's data is not going to bind to that model!

Comment: @StephenMuecke : fixed.

Comment: Not yet :)  `selectedMail` is a collection of an model containing properties `Item` and `Value` (ditto for `selectedMobile`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke : but see OP has parsed that object into string. `selectedMail: JSON.stringify(selectedMail)`

Comment: And I noted that is incorrect in my comment above :)

Comment: @AmitKumar and what if i want to use `selectedMail: selectedMail` instead of  selectedMail: JSON.stringify(selectedMail)?

Comment: @alkavaghela : Then You need to create a model for that too. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JavaScriptSerializer` as you are using JSON.stringify() it will pass data in string format to you action method, Instead of `string[]` parameter use `string` in you action method

```
// Custom class
public class Test
{
    public string categoryId {get;set;}
    public List<Mail> selectedMail {get;set;}
    public List<Mail> selectedMobile {get; set;}
}

 public ActionResult UtilityEmailSMS(string data)
 {
      JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      var list= serializer.Deserialize<List<Test>>(data);
      return View();
 }
```